# z3py: Why BitVecVal(5,3) is smaller than BitVecVal(8,3)

Tags: z3, z3py

Here is my code:

```
from z3 import *

a = BitVecVal(5,3)
b = BitVecVal(8,3)

print a
print b

s = Solver()

s.add(a<b)

print s.check()
print s.model()
```

The output is

```
5
0
sat
```

Could someone help me understand why 'a' is smaller than 'b'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

< is signed comparison.

5 = -3

8 = 0

so, yes, -3 < 0.